# What is difference between fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize { s.len() } and fn some_function2(s: &String) -> usize { s.len() }?

Tags: rust, reference

I'm new to rust so I apologize in advance if my question is dumb.  Can someone tell me how references work in rust? I've read the documentation and I'm unable to understand it.

My question is: What is difference between

```rs
fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize {
    s.len()
}
```

and

```rs
fn some_function2(s: &String) -> usize {
    s.len()
}
```

I have asked "ChatGPT" and got this:

> The main difference between some_function1 and some_function2 is in how the function accepts the input parameter s.
>
> In some_function1, the input parameter s is a reference to a String object. The & before the parameter s specifies that the function is borrowing a reference to the String object passed in as an argument. This means that the function does not take ownership of the String object and cannot modify it. The function returns the length of the String object using the len() method.
>
> In some_function2, the input parameter s is a reference to a String object, but it is not a borrowed reference. The & is used to indicate that the function is borrowing the reference to the String object. This means that the function cannot modify the String object and does not take ownership of it. The function also returns the length of the String object using the len() method.
>
> So the difference between the two functions is that some_function1 takes a borrowed reference to a String object, while some_function2 takes a reference to a String object, but also borrows it. In general, it is recommended to use borrowed references whenever possible to avoid unnecessary ownership transfers and to prevent unnecessary copying of data.

from what I understand is both are correct and useable? how can you reference to a data type in some_function2? [&String]

Please help me out!

I ran this:

```rs
fn main(){

    let s = String::from("hello");

    let z = String::from("World");

    println!("lenght of s is: {}", some_function1(s));
    println!("lenght of z is: {}", some_function2(z));
}

fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize{
    s.len()
}

fn some_function2(z: &String) -> usize{
    z.len()
}
```

got this:

```rs
rustc /tmp/lHkDSH6rQp/main.rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> /tmp/lHkDSH6rQp/main.rs:8:48
   |
8  |     println!("lenght of z is: {}", some_function2(z));
   |                                    -------------- ^
   |                                    |              |
expected `&String`, found struct `String`
help: consider borrowing here: `&z`
arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
note: function defined here
  --> /tmp/lHkDSH6rQp/main.rs:15:4
   |
15 | fn some_function2(z: &String) -> usize{
   |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----------

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> /tmp/lHkDSH6rQp/main.rs:11:19
   |
11 | fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize{
expected due to this
   |                   |
expected struct `String`, found reference
   |
note: expected struct `String`
found reference `&_`
help: to take parameter `s` by reference, move `&` to the type
   |
11 - fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize{
11 + fn some_function1(s: &String) -> usize{
   |

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd want `&s: String`. You see that notation used with `self` vs. `&self` but that is a special case argument.

Comment: Not an answer, but a probably helpful read - https://h2co3.github.io/pattern/

Comment: The chatgpt quote is completely wrong. Don't use chatgpt for things that you can't already verify.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, but I can't find the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is pretty evident, the first one [can't be compiled](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn+some_function1%28%26s%3A+String%29+-%3E+usize+%7B+s.len%28%29+%7D+%0A). The error message says you need to replace `&s: String` with `s: &String`. You may read the type aloud like “a reference (`&`) to `String`”.

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:1:19
  |
1 | fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize { s.len() } 
  |                   ^^  ------ expected due to this
  |                   |
  |                   expected `String`, found `&_`
  |
  = note: expected struct `String`
          found reference `&_`
help: to take parameter `s` by reference, move `&` to the type
  |
1 - fn some_function1(&s: String) -> usize { s.len() } 
1 + fn some_function1(s: &String) -> usize { s.len() }
```

What is the other way to fix it? Let's apply *pattern matching* to the [argument](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#function-parameters). We have a reference (`&`) to a reference (`&`) to a `String`, and we “dereference” it once `&s`.

```rust
fn some_function1(&s: &&String) -> usize { s.len() }
                      ^^
```